# How do I pass variables to loops within includes?

Tags: templating, include

How do I pass variables to a loop within an include?

This is my partial:

```
{% for photo in photos %}
    <img src="{{ photo.projectPhotos_photo_image.first().getUrl('projectThumbnail') }}"
{% endfor %}
```

I'm calling it from a template with this:

```
{% set projectEntries = craft.entries({
    section: 'project'
}) %}
{% set vars = {
    photos: projectEntries
    } 
%}
{% include "_partials/photo-tile.html" with vars %}
```

All well and good

*but*

What if I want to abstract this from my partial:

```
src="{{ photo.projectPhotos_photo_image.first().getUrl('projectThumbnail') }}"
```

In other words, I'd like to pass the src, `{{ photo.projectPhotos_photo_image.first().getUrl('projectThumbnail') }}` , into the partial but I don't know how!

If I try to do it from the template like this (through `photoSrc`), it fails, saying the 'photo' is undefined:

```
{% set vars = {
    section: "category",
    category: category,
    pageOneTitle:  categoryTitle,
    photos: projectEntries,
    photoSrc: photo.projectPhotos_photo_image.first().getUrl('projectThumbnail')
    } 
%}
```

Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

You can't reference a variable (`photo`) created inside the partial loop outside the partial (and loop) – it doesn't exist yet – so what you're trying to achieve isn't possible.

What you could do, is to abstract the important bits, namely the field and transform handles:

```
{% set vars = {
    photos: projectEntries,
    photoField: 'projectPhotos_photo_image',
    photoTransform: 'projectThumbnail'
} %}
{% include "_partials/photo-tile.html" with vars %}
```

And inside your partial:

```
{% for photo in photos %}
   <img src="{{ photo[photoField].first().getUrl(photoTransform) }}" />
{% endfor %}
```

If that doesn't cut it, you'll probably want to use a [macro](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/tags/macro.html):

```
{# Your macro file, e.g. /templates/_macros/photoTile.html #}
{% macro src(photo) %}
    {{ photo.projectPhotos_photo_image.first().getUrl('projectThumbnail') }}
{% endmacro %}

{# Inside your partial #}
{% from '_macros/photoTile' import src %}
{% for photo in photos %}
    <img src="{{- src(photo) -}}" />
{% endfor %}
```

(If you're wondering about the `{{- -}}` syntax in the above example, the dashes are just to remove whitespace from the rendered src string – you also wrap the code inside the macro in `{% spaceless %}{% endspaceless %}` tags.)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried your first idea and it failed. I think that the macro would work but this is a lot of hassle in an attempt to make a componentized, partial-based system. I'm going to experiment with https://vuejs.org